# How can stop, restart or see console log of startup application?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I set that binary to run startup using ubuntu Startup Application. After restart application is running but I don't know how to see it's console log or stop or restart it.

Comment: If it's running out of your X session, it's probably logging to `~/.Xsession-errors` or similar

Comment: This question is likely to be closed as being a better fit for Super User, but it is probably too short to post anywhere. It needs more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can find the PID of your application using:

```
ps -a | grep <PROCESS-NAME>
```

After that, you can attach to the process with certain PID and observe the standard output and standard error using (to detach press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>):

```
strace -p <PID> -e write=1,2
```

If you want to stop your application, your can terminate it:

```
kill -SIGTERM <PID>
```

or using process name:

```
pkill <PROCESS-NAME>
```